# How safe is Vesterbro, Copenhagen?

Tags: safety, security, copenhagen

I am going to stay alone at the Zleep hotel in the Vesterbro area in Copenhagen in October. Reading reviews of the hotel I see reports of lots of prostitutes and homeless drug addicts hanging around it, and that there's lots of fighting and screaming on the streets during the nights.

The hotel seems to be located near both Istegade and Hamltorvet, which on Wikipedia are specifically mentioned as places with prostitution and drug trafficking.

How safe is this area of Copenhagen? Would it be recommendable to return alone to the hotel late at night?

Comment: I've never been attacked by a prostitute or a homeless drug user. What are you asking? If such people exist there? If they're violent? If they're noisy?

Comment: If you have read those reviews, and are now aware that they may be true, whether or not you will feel safe is ultimately something we cannot aid you in determining.

Answer (score 6):

With the hotel being in the middle of the Copenhagen red light district, it can't be a great surprise that it's noisy outside at night.

In this area, you are also most likely to see both prostitutes, drug addicts and dealers hanging around. I might be ignorant and wouldn't consider any place in Copenhagen to be unsafe, but is there a particular reason why you assume that these persons are a threat to your safety?

Comment: When I booked it I didn't know that the hotel was located in a red light district or that Copenhagen had one.

Comment: I'm not used to hanging around drug addicts but I assume many of them are desperate for money and might also be stoned and of erratic mind.  Drug dealers break the law for a living and might not have any qualms about breaking a few more.

Comment: If anyone in that area have an erratic mind, it's more likely all the drunk tourists. But honestly, drug addicts are usually quite decent people and IMHO absolutely nothing to worry about. You can also expect the drug dealers to avoid anything drawing unnecessary attention to their 'work'.

Comment: Stoned people seem to me to be a lot less scary (if potentially more annoying) than anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

It is a safe as any other major city; just use common sense.

Keep your valuables in the hotel safe (carry photocopie of your passport for example).

In areas with a lot of people, always keep an eye on your stuff (wallet, bags...).

Do not look like a tourist... dress smart (as European mostly do).

Obvious: Do not participate in prostitution, do not participate in drug dealings...

Other than that, have fun, enjoy.